# Does memcache store cache for each user?

Tags: php, caching, memcached

i know this might probably a noob/silly question but I haven't really found any answer to it.
I'm using Php memcached, my question is.

**for example:**

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) 
                or die ("Could not connect");
$memcache->set('entryNonStandardVars',$nonStandardVars,false,420);
```

will each user have individual 'entryNonStandardVars' keys? If not is there a possibility to store a cache individually or per user cache? using memcache of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's exactly *one* memcache store. Memcache doesn't have any concept of who your users are.
You can simply store your data under different keys:

```
$memcache->set("entryNonStandardVars_$userId", ...);
```